# The 'lines' command in R

Tags: r, histogram, lines, density-plot

Just a quick question:
I'm trying to add a density line to my histogram

```
lines(x,dbeta(x,6,3))
```

I've previously defined:

```
 x = runif(100000,0,1)
```

However rather than 'joining the dots' of the beta distribution, it 'fills in with colour' the whole are under it. So I'm basically left with a coloured in beta distribution overlayed on my histogram.

I've tried changing the line types, but this doesn't seem to help. How can I just make it into a single-lined overlayed plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are plotting pairs of random numbers with it's corresponding density... if you simply want to overlay the line, don't use `runif()`, but `seq()`:

```
x <- seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=10000)
lines(x, dbeta(x, 6,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `ggplot2`

```
x = runif(100000,0,1)
x = data.frame(beta=dbeta(x,6,3))
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(x, aes(beta)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
                 binwidth=.1,
                 colour="red", fill="white") +
  geom_density(alpha=.2)
```

[image]